# angularjs resource pass an array of object parameter but is null in api controller

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing, angular-resource

I have an angularjs resource as seen below:

```
  return $resource('/api/report',
     { },
     {
       save: { method: 'POST', url: '/api/fileupload/savefile', isArray: false },
     });
```

My angularjs controller that uses this resource is below:

```
$scope.save = function () {
            var reportFieldsSample = [{ Field: 'ff', Value: 'gg' }, { Field: 'aa', Value: 'dd' }];
            Report.save({ reportParams: reportFieldsSample},
                { },
                function (content) {
                    console.log(content);
                });
```

My WebApiConfig for this route is:

```
   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        "SaveFile",
        "api/fileupload/savefile",
        new { controller = "FileUpload", action = "SaveFile" },
        new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("POST") });
```

My mvc api controller that receives this is below:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage SaveFile(IList<Parameter> reportParams)
    {
        //reportParams is null
    }
```

Parameter class is declared in this way:

```
public class Parameter
{
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

The request enters my api controller but the `reportParams` argument of the controller is always null.
Can you help me point out the problem? Thanks

Comment: Can you try to send data as `Report.save(reportFieldsSample,...)` and see if it works

Comment: it has an error:
TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'push'

Comment: Client side or server side error?

Comment: client side.. i found the error in the browser's console log

Comment: TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'push';
at copy (http://localhost:54429/Scripts/angular.js:826:9); at Resource (http://localhost:54429/Scripts/angular-resource.js:433:9)

Comment: Ok,save method on client side does not support array, since it should be a single resource. Can you change the server model object such that reportParams has a child property `IList<Parameters> reportParams`. Instead of directly passing a list.

Comment: nice, it works now.. could you answer it so i can choose your answer

Comment: I have added the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that you are getting null in you web api controller is because the structure you are sending from client is not matching the server parameter declaration.

What you can do on the server side is to declare object such as

```
class ReportParamsModel {
  public IList<Parameters> reportParams {get; set;}
}
```

You controller method becomes

`public HttpResponseMessage SaveFile(ReportParamsModel params)`

and you are set to go

You can also use the dynamic support in webapi, where the controller method becomes

```
public HttpResponseMessage SaveFile(dynamic data) {
    //data.reportParams contains you array (but each object again is a dynamic object.
}
```